# Script doens't call a program with cron or rc.local, but works fine standalone?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a script that check is my c++ program is already running, and if not, call it again.

```
#! /bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/home/pi/siscat/LogFile
case "$(/bin/pidof sisCAT | /usr/bin/wc -w)" in
0) /usr/bin/sudo  /usr/bin/screen -md -S sisCAT /home/pi/siscat/sisCAT 
    echo $(/bin/date)"      sisCAT reinitialize">> $LOG_FILE
    ;;
1)  echo $(/bin/date)"      sisCAT is already running">> $LOG_FILE
    # all ok
    ;;
esac
```

sisCAT is my c++ system and run on raspberry pi.
When I run it from terminal with `./isRunning.sh`  works fine, but when i create a crontab entry for this script like

`* * * * * /home/pi/siscat/isRunning.sh`

every minute cron call the script but the script do not call sisCAT, I've tried to put my `env` output in the script, but my problem persist.

Comment: The `sudo` might the problem. Do you really need to run the program as root? See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script.

Comment: No, i put the sudo trying a solution to my problem, but not worked, a user delete him answer, he ask me to put the full path of `wc ` `pidof` etc.

Comment: tje program run as root, because the cronjob is on  root scheduler

Comment: Try saving the `stderr` output from `sudo` with e.g. `2>$LOG_FILE` and see if says anything.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your email?  Does it update the log file?

Comment: I don't get error messages because the script execute, but this line no `0)  /usr/bin/screen -md -S sisCAT /home/pi/siscat/sisCAT `

Comment: The output of `stderr` don't says anything